# BIRT 4.4.2 Table in a Grid xls

Tags: birt, birt-emitter

I have a BIRT report containing a grid. In the first column first row, there is a chart. In the first column second row, there is a table which has multiple columns. When exporting to Excel using the spudsoft emitter, the columns of the table are merged together so that the entire table only occupies one column in excel.

How do I have my table properly occupy a corresponding number of excel columns? For example can I have my chart span multiple merged columns in a row?

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this problem I usually use the same amount of columns in a Grid I have in my table.
You can merge multiple cells in the second row of the grid and place the table there.